# Why does FTP require port number to be split?

Tags: ftp, rfc

I recently had to implement a FTP client (in active mode). Something I found remarkable in RFC 959 is the fact that the port number should be split into 8-bits for the `PORT` command.

An example: when using port 20000 on the client, this should binary be split. 20000 base 10 = 0100111000100000 base 2. This should be split into 01001110 and 00100000, which are resp. 78 and 32. These numbers should be sent as plaintext digits.

Is there any reason why the standard chose this approach? It seems weird both from an efficiency and an easy to debug standpoint.

Comment: *"These numbers should be sent as binary coded digits"* - The numbers are sent in a plain text. Not as *"binary coded digits"*. - Anyway, I do not think your question is on-topic here. I also doubt anyone here knows, why authors on RFC 959 choose this encoding 30 years ago - The encoding is actually rather simple: `(port/256) + "," + (port%256)`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'm aware of this implementation, it would just make more sense to just use `port` instead of having to apply some math at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any reason why the standard chose this approach?

This is likely lost in history. But probably the typical format for IP:Port as used today was not established at this time (this was way before HTTP and the syntax of URLs) so encoding a sockaddr_in with its 4 byte IP and 2 byte port as a sequence of 6 numbers delimited by comma probably made some sense.

> It seems weird both from an efficiency and an easy to debug standpoint.

FTP is a text based protocol. Efficiency was obviously not a design criteria - otherwise it would have been done all binary. Having a sequence of 6 bytes instead of IP:port is fine for debugging if the layer where the debugging is done is C code and your are effectively dealing with a 6 byte addressing (4 byte IP, 2 byte port) in the form of a sockaddr_in struct.